# convert php preg_replace to C#

Tags: c#, php, preg-replace

How would I convert this php code to C#:

```
echo preg_replace('/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/i', '${0}o${0}', 'david');
// output: dodavovidod
```

I've tried with this, but it didn't work:

```
string s1 = "david";
string s2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s1, "$o$", "/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/i");
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: It doesn't take `$0o$0`?

Comment: I think if you read the documentation for `Regex.Replace()` you'd very quickly see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = Regex.Replace("david", "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]", "$0o$0" );
```

Comment: Don't forget `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`